# Unable to instantiate Quartz job in spring

Tags: quartz-scheduler

At the start up , I get the following error in quartz Spring. Any help is appreciated

`` org.quartz.SchedulerException: Job instantiation failed
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.AdaptableJobFactory.newJob(AdaptableJobFactory.java:61) ~[spring-context-support-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.initialize(JobRunShell.java:140) ~[quartz-1.8.6.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:364) [quartz-1.8.6.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to execute job class [com.ezdi.business.AutoSendMail]: only [org.quartz.Job] and [java.lang.Runnable] supported.
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.AdaptableJobFactory.adaptJob(AdaptableJobFactory.java:99) ~[spring-context-support-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.AdaptableJobFactory.newJob(AdaptableJobFactory.java:58) ~[spring-context-support-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]` ``

Comment: From the stacktrace, it seems your com.ezdi.business.AutoSendMail is not either a Runnable instance or a Quartz job instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your AutoSendMail class doesn't implement org.quartz.Job interface